# CruiseControl.NET and NAnt

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have a CC.NET project configured to call a common NAnt build file, which does some stuff, and then calls a child NAnt build file. The child build file name is specified by CC.NET to the command build file using a property.

The hurdle that I am trying to get over is that the common build file log gets overwritten by the child build file log, so I don't get the common build log in the CC.NET build log.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

I thought about changing the child build's log, but reading up on the NAnt `<nant>` task doesn't allow me to change the child's output log.

Comment: People, please use the comments for comments, don't comment in an answer. The answer is supposed to provide (a large % of) the solution, not a request for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [nant task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc1/help/tasks/nant.html), so you get one single build file.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way that you could *include* the child nant file as opposed to executing it as a full-fledged child nant project? This would prevent the overwrite, but not sure if it's possible in your situation.